# Telugu books dedicated for namajapa

Tags: scripture, translation, nama-japa, telugu

I asked several questions related to namajapa on our site. Some of them with short answers are given below

[Can Rama Nama Japa give moksha?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/40369/can-rama-nama-japa-give-moksha) Yes

[Is any god name eligible for nama japa?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/51746/is-any-god-name-eligible-for-nama-japa) Yes

[Is there any relation between (nama) Japa and breath?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/51804/is-there-any-relation-between-nama-japa-and-breath) Seems True

[Is 'nama japa without bhava' automatically converts into 'namajapa with bhava'?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/52291/is-nama-japa-without-bhava-automatically-converts-into-namajapa-with-bhava) Yes

When one goes through those questions and answers, it is easy to learn that namajapa is a simple path to get all the benefits that can be achieved by complex sadhanas.

But if we check the other paths like

1. Yoga, there are several books such as Patanjali yoga sutras, Hatha yoga pradipika, etc.,
2. Vedanta, There are several books like Tripura rahasya, yoga Vashishtha, etc.,

All the books mentioned in the above two points are available in Telugu also. These books explicitly give the details of the stages that a sadhaka goes through from the starting point to till attaining Moksha.

I want to read the same for namajapa. But when I try to search for those books, almost all of them were [not available in Telugu](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/52347/english-or-telugu-translations-of-works-of-bodhendra-saraswathi). So I want to find a Telugu book that encompasses all the details from the starting point to attaining higher States.

Is there any Telugu book that is explicitly dedicated to namajapa and covers all the stages of the sadhaka who is doing namajapa?

Comment: There are some apps like Stotra Nidhi which have almost all stotras. They do have mantras too.

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru Does it cover all the stages that a sadhaka goes through? And I am in search of a scripture.

Comment: I dont think so but try it once

Comment: Okay @SethuSrivatsaKoduru Thanks.

Comment: if you are comfortable with google translate then you can use some ocr website and stranslate it

Comment: @YOuwillnotknow There will be some scriptural specific words that can be translated incorrectly.

Comment: that being true, but is telegu too different from tamizh?

Comment: @YOuwillnotknow Yeah, Tamil is different from Telugu. Most of the books about nama japa is available in Tamil.

Comment: there is some bangla book of goswami disciple of chaitanya mahaprabhu, that will surely have a translation

Answer (score 1):

After a long search, I found the following book

[**NAMA MAHIMA - NAMA RAHASYAMU** BY SRILA JAGADANANDA PANDIT](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.389669/page)

It is a Telugu book dedicated to Nama Japa.
Although I didn't read it entirely, the preface I read convinces me that the book covers all the important details that are required for a sadhaka of nama Japa.

The two parts of the book Nama Mahima and Nama Rahasyanmu are taken from the book named **Prema Vivarta by Srila Jagadananda Pandita**. Although the book *Prema Vivarta* contains many other contents, the aspects related to nama Japa are taken and translated into Telugu by T*ridandi Sri Bhakti Damodara Maharaju*.

Comment: For Tamil and English, this site is the best https://namalayam.org/